# How can I implement an 'application default' section header view for all of my application's UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My application uses `UITableView`s throughout, so with this I want to be able to give all of their section header's the same view.

Rather than just copying and pasting the code into each of the `UITableView`s delegates, where would I place the necessary override method of `- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` to make sure that the `UITableView`s section header is always the custom view I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subclass of whatever contains your tableview (probably a view controller). Then put your `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` code in this controller. Import the header from this subclass into all of your view controllers and make them a subclass of it

```
#import "CustomTableViewControlThing.h"
@interface NameOfViewController : CustomTableViewControlThing
```

Comment: This works great! However, how do I access the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` method?

Comment: What do you need to do with it? It depends.

Comment: I need to add the header text into my custom `UIView`s label

Comment: You can't reference a subclass's data from a superclass. You should put a reference to the label in your custom `UIView` in your superclass and then change it in your subclass.

Comment: I created an NSArray property in the superclass, and filled it within the subclass, is this what you meant? It works now though, so thanks!